# Show text after user clicks play button with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to display text after 5 seconds when the user clicks the play button on the video. My HTML looks like this:

```
<video width="100%" controls autoplay>
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>


 <p id="showMe" style="display:none;">
  this is text
</p>
```

So far my JS code looks like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {    
   $('#showMe').delay(5000).show(0); 
});
```

This code works fine, but I am trying to achieve that text appears in 5 seconds when user click play button. 
Cna somebody tries to help me with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `on play` event

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {    
   
   
   $('video').on('play', function (e) {
      $('#showMe').delay(5000).show(0); 
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video width="100%" controls autoplay>
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>


 <p id="showMe" style="display:none;">
  this is text
</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use video `onplay` event. Check out fiddle.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {       
   
   var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
   vid.onplay = function() {
    $('#showMe').delay(5000).show(0);
   };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video id="myVideo" width="100%" controls autoplay>
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>


 <p id="showMe" style="display:none;">
  this is text
</p>
```